# Get data from two tables from single stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one is for task and one for all jobs. I am giving `departmentid` to `sp` and want to get all the `jobid` from task table and job table and return all detail of these jobs from `jobid` table. Please tell me if there is any solution.

This is my task table:

[image]

This is my job table:

[image]

In task table the parameter `departmentid` goes to `AssignedToDepartmentId`. In `JobId` table the parameter `depatmentid` goes to `DepartmentId`.

First get all `jobid` from both tables by `departmentid` and then get details of all `jobid` and return detail of `jobid`.

these are my tasktable entries
[image]

these are my jobid table entries
[image]

if I pass 7 as `departmentid` parameter then I should get all the columns of `jobid` table of two `jobid` "series" and `Opportunity1005`.

Comment: Please, provide DDL for your tables, samples of data, required output and code you tried. Describe specific problem you have encountered with your code.

Comment: i have attached all detail...please give me a solution

Comment: It is not a code writing service, it is a Q&A site. You really think someone, will take a text from your pictures, creates sample tables and write query for you??

Answer (score 0):

simple try this

```
CREATE PROC p_GetTableData
@DepartmentId INT
AS 
BEGIN

    SELECT jt.* FROM Task_Table tt INNER JOIN JobId_Table jt ON tt.JobId  = jt.jobId
    WHERE tt.AssignByDepatmentId = @DepartmentId

END
```